# Fonts of my website not working on iOS devices

Tags: ios, css, web, font-face

I am using @font-face to load the fonts I host on my server and use for a website I am currently developing. The fonts are working fine everywhere except on iOS devices (iPhone, iPad). When I test the website on online iOS devices simulators, like ipadpeek.com, it works fine but when testing them on the website itself it's not working.

This is how I embed my fonts using @font-face

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'droid_arabic_kufiregular';
    src: url('css/fonts/droidkufi-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('css/fonts/droidkufi-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('css/fonts/droidkufi-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('css/fonts/droidkufi-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('css/fonts/droidkufi-regular-webfont.svg#droid_arabic_kufiregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'droid_arabic_kufiregular';
    src: url('css/fonts/droidkufi-blod-webfont.eot');
    src: url('css/fonts/droidkufi-blod-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('css/fonts/droidkufi-blod-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('css/fonts/droidkufi-blod-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('css/fonts/droidkufi-blod-webfont.svg#droid_arabic_kufiregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Any clues?

Comment: Only svg fonts are supported on webkit, so make sure your svg files are properly referenced and that they are actually uploaded (see the table on this page for compatibility: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webfonts/quick/)

Comment: I made sure but everything is fine, files are on server and properly referenced for, checked file names to avoid case sensitivity but everything seems fine!

Answer (score 0):

Did you use FontSquirrel to convert your font?
See if the fix in this post helps:
http://blog.echoenduring.com/2011/12/01/quick-tip-svg-fonts-font-face/